# How to convert an array of NSString to an array of c-strings?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, c-strings

I have an `NSArray<NSString*>*` object, and I need to invoke a C API which takes in an array of strings as `char**`.

What's the best way to do this? The important note is the c-strings must not have a `const` modifier, so something like the following isn't good enough since `UTF8String` returns `const char*`:

```
NSArray<NSString*>* names = ...;
int len = args.count;
char* cNames[len];
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    cNames[i] = names[i].UTF8String;
};
```

Comment: Will the C API change the content of the strings?

Comment: I do not believe so, but in theory it could.

Comment: If it does, nothing will make that modify the original NSArray. The above is basically the right approach. You just want to add the tedious `malloc` and `strncpy` to create a full copy. The answer is: the above, plus C.

Comment: Don't know where your strings are coming from, but be aware of multi-byte "characters" in these emoji-filled times. If your C API is not Unicode-aware and your strings are not ASCII-except-in-name you'll get strange results.

Comment: Good point, I may need to use the platform specific encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do some dynamic memory as you cannot rely on the backing memory for UTF8String being released.

```
NSArray *strings = @[ @"String 1", @"Other string", @"Random String"];
char **cStrings = NULL;
NSInteger numCStrings = strings.count;

if (numCStrings) {
    cStrings = (char **)calloc(numCStrings, sizeof(char*))  ;

    if (cStrings) {
        // Safer to allocate memory for each string

        for (NSInteger i=0;i<numCStrings;i++) {
            NSString *nsString = strings[i];
            char *cString = (char *)malloc([nsString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1); // + 1 for \0

            if (cString) {
                strcpy(cString, nsString.UTF8String);
                cStrings[i] = cString;
            } else {
                // You should handle your error
            }
        }
    } else {
        // You should handle your error
    }
}

for (NSInteger i=0;i<numCStrings;i++) {
    NSLog(@"C-String (%ld): %s", i, cStrings[i]);
}

// Note you need to free your memory later!
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
for (NSInteger i=0;i<numCStrings;i++) {
    if (cStrings[i]) {
        // Free each string
        free(cStrings[i]);
    }
}

// Free the array
free(cStrings);

cStrings = NULL;
numCStrings = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. Ugly but I guess it will have to do!

Comment: One minor correction - `nsString.length` returns the length in the UTF-16 encoding. Need to use `[nsString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`